# laravel4 one to one relationship can not load the relationship

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4

1. I have two tables like this:

**users**

```
id      email
1     abc@ibm.com
2     abc@hp.com
3     abc@google.com
```

**grp_members**

```
grp_id    user_id
1          2
2          2
13         1
13         3
```

2.My model

There, one group member must be a user, so its a one to one relationship just for GroupMember.

Users model about table users

```
class Users extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "users";
}
```

GroupMember model about table group_members

```
class GroupMember extends BaseModel{

    protected $table = "grp_members";

    public function user(){
        return $this -> hasOne('Users', 'id');
    }
}
```

3.In my service `GroupApi.php`, if I have a query like this

```
class GroupApi {

    public function queryGroupMembers(){

        $result = GroupMember::all();

        var_dump(get_class(GroupMember::all())); //CODE ONE

        foreach($result as $ret){
            var_dump(get_class($ret));  //CODE TWO
            var_dump(get_class($ret -> user));  //CODE THREE
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, when I invoke `var_dump(get_class(GroupMember::all()))` at **CODE ONE**,
I got this

```
.string(39) "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection"
```

Yes, that's what I want.

Now, at **CODE TWO**, it prints

```
string(11) "GroupMember"
```

Yes, also correct object, but when the code goes to **CODE THREE**, it give me a surprise,
the outputs like this:

```
string(8) "GroupApi"
```

Why its an instance of GroupApi, but not the instance of **`Users`** or **`GroupMember`**

And in that case , how can I invoke `$ret -> user`?

Any idea is welcome, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things I'm not sure I understand in your implementation but something that could be causing you troubles is not using the [conventions Laravel asks for](https://tower.la.utexas.edu/index.php/docs/database/eloquent#conventions), that being using User as the model name and users (model + s) as the table name.

Also, i would guess $g1 is not a GroupMember object as you suggest, could you getClass() it and comfirm?

Comment: thanks man , yes , $g1 is not a GroupMember object, I modify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess you have 3 tables:

users; grp_members; groups

and a many-to-many relationship between users and groups using the table grp_members as pivot table.

In this case, try this:

Class User:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'grp_members');
    }

}
```

Class Group:

```
class Group extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User','grp_members');
    }

}
```

And also change the field name in the table 'grp_members' from grp_id to group_id, to follow eloquent conventions.

Comment: thanks man , thats a typo error, I've modify my tables's name.

Comment: After, I removed the id here `$this -> hasOne('Users', 'id')`, I got errors. `Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.group_member_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`group_member_id` is null limit 1) (Bindings: array (
))`

Comment: thanks. Still can't get what I want. I use the same code as yours, and at **`CODE THREE`** , I still got the result : **`string(8) "GroupApi"`**

Comment: Also check this section in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships